# Optimal way to import specifically formatted time values

Tags: date-and-time

This is admittedly boring but one needs such things occasionally, and I could not find it documented.

I have specific time format like "20160723 170543518" (YearMonthDay HourMinuteSecondMillisecond, it is from forex historical data in ASCII), and I want to transform a csv file with such first column into a, say, time series as efficiently as possible.

What I tried is

```
DateObject[{StringInsert[First[x], " ", {5, 7, 12, 14, 16}], {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "Millisecond"}}]
```

but it is quite slow, and I am pretty sure there must be more efficient way to do it.

So?

Comment: Are month, day. hour, minute, and second always in two-digit format?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, and milliseconds take last three positions, it is exactly like this, constant width strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method that may work for you.  I'll describe it in two sections.

**Concept**

We start with one line of string data, split it into pieces with `StringTake` and convert to integers with `FromDigits`.  Then we use `Join` to assemble a list of 6 numeric values that can be fed into `DateObject` or `AbsoluteTime`.

```
sdata = "20160723 170543518";
split = StringTake[sdata, {{1, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8},
   {10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}, {16, 18}}]
ndata = FromDigits /@ split
tList = Join[ndata[[1 ;; 5]], {ndata[[6]] + ndata[[7]]/1000}]
DateObject[tList]
DateString[%]
```

Okay, so that works on one line of data.  How about many lines?

**Implementation**

For many lines we create a function that can be applied to each line.  Our function takes the concepts above and puts them into a single function.  We then generate a list of data points, to simulate a Forex data file, and test the function on the data points with `Timing`.

```
Remove[toDateObj]
toDateObj[s_String] := DateObject[
  Join[#[[1 ;; 5]], {#[[6]] + #[[7]]/1000}] &@
   (FromDigits /@ StringTake[s,
      {{1, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8},
       {10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}, {16, 18}}])
  ]
forex = Table[sdata, {30000}];
Timing[toDateObj /@ forex;]

(* {0.98978, Null} *)
```

So, 30000 lines of data in less than one second, which, of course, will be different on other machines.  How to speed it up?  Using `AbsoluteTime` instead of `DateObject` runs in about 0.5 seconds.  And ignoring the seconds & milliseconds runs in about 0.35 seconds.  Here's what that might look like:

```
Remove[toAbsTime]
toAbsTime[s_String] := AbsoluteTime[
  FromDigits /@ StringTake[s,
    {{1, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8},
     {10, 11}, {12, 13}}]
  ]

Timing[toAbsTime /@ forex;]

{0.341537, Null}
```

**Comparison**

To make a comparison to your original code,

```
Timing[DateObject[
     {StringInsert[#, " ", {5, 7, 12, 14, 16}],
      {"Year", "Month", "Day",
       "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "Millisecond"}}] &
   /@ forex;]

(* {10.2784, Null} *)
```

Looks like about 20-30 times faster.

An earlier version of this answer used `ToExpression`.  A great speed improvement was realized by using `FromDigits` instead, thanks to the comment by @J.M.

Comment: `FromDigits[]` is safer than `ToExpression[]` for converting integer strings.

Comment: Great! Unfortunately I need these milliseconds. Still, it is at least 6x faster! Except frankly speaking I don't really understand why :D

Comment: Great comment by @J.M .  I tried it and got a significant speed improvement, in addition to being safer.  So much of a speed improvement that I edited my answer.